# Change an element's text without affecting sibling tags (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, drupal

I'm trying to modify this bit of HTML with jQuery to delete the duplicate arrow:

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
<a href="/spa/">Home</a> »  » <a href="/spa/image/tid">Image galleries</a>
</div>
```

I'm not having much luck, however, in that replacing the string using the replace() function seems to strip the HTML tags as well, leaving:

```
<div class="breadcrumb">Home » Image galleries</div>
```

My existing dodgy code is:

```
$('.breadcrumb').each(function() { 
    var mytext = $(this); 
    var mytext2 = mytext.text(); 
    mytext.text(mytext2.replace(' » » ',' » ')); 
});
```

Any ideas?

Cheers,
James

Comment: We need to see the jQuery code to diagnose this.

Comment: I appreciate that markup should not ideally be fixed using jQuery, however I do not want to modify the Drupal side of it for reasons that are too long to go into right now..!

My existing dodgy code is:

$('.breadcrumb').each(function() {
  var mytext = $(this);
  var mytext2 = mytext.text();
  mytext.text(mytext2.replace(' »  » ',' » '));
});

Comment: It's because you're using the `.text()` jQuery method.  You need to use `.html()` instead - see my answer for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're modifying the code using `innerText` or jQuery's `.text()`.  When using these, HTML is stripped out and only the text is returned.  Use `.innerHTML` or `.html()` instead.

Using your "dodgy" code:

```
$('.breadcrumb').each(function() {  
    var mytext = $(this);  
    var mytext2 = mytext.html();  
    mytext.html(mytext2.replace(' » » ',' » '));  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove arrow via these in template.php of your theme: http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_breadcrumb/6 as YOURTHEME_breadcrumb function.

Comment: +1 This is the Drupal way. JavaScript is a great tool but not the solution here.